# Reshaping Data in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, reshape

Are there any way to re-shape data in the following format?

```
    Date       Student Test.1 Test.2 Test.3 
    2007/02/01   A      80      90     70  
    2007/02/01   B      90      60     90  
    2007/02/01   C      75      70     80  
    2007/02/01   D      50      80     70
```

To the following format?

```
    Date       Student Result  Test 
    2007/02/01   A      80       1   
    2007/02/01   A      90       2   
    2007/02/01   A      70       3   
    2007/02/01   B      90       1   
    2007/02/01   B      60       2   
    2007/02/01   B      90       3   
    2007/02/01   C      75       1   
    2007/02/01   C      70       2   
    2007/02/01   C      80       3   
    2007/02/01   D      50       1   
    2007/02/01   D      80       2
    2007/02/01   D      70       3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `melt()` function may be helpful:

```
library(reshape)
md <- melt(df, id=c('Date','Student')
```

The resulting 'melted'  data frame will be something like this:

```
      Date Student variable value
2007/02/01       A    Test.1   80
2007/02/01       B    Test.1   90
2007/02/01       C    Test.1   75
2007/02/01       D    Test.1   50
2007/02/01       A    Test.1   90
...
```

You can then rename the columns and/or modify the values to fit your needs.

The melted data frame can then be used with the `cast()` function to create pivot-like data frames. Check [the Quick-R tutorial: Reshaping data](http://statmethods.net/management/reshape.html).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do:

```
reshape(x, direction='long', varying=paste('Test', 1:3, sep='.'))
          Date Student time Test id
1.1 2007/02/01       A    1   80  1
2.1 2007/02/01       B    1   90  2
3.1 2007/02/01       C    1   75  3
4.1 2007/02/01       D    1   50  4
1.2 2007/02/01       A    2   90  1
2.2 2007/02/01       B    2   60  2
3.2 2007/02/01       C    2   70  3
4.2 2007/02/01       D    2   80  4
1.3 2007/02/01       A    3   70  1
2.3 2007/02/01       B    3   90  2
3.3 2007/02/01       C    3   80  3
4.3 2007/02/01       D    3   70  4
```

You can then rename the columns as necessary.  Note that the `time` column here is what you label as `Test` in your desired output.  This is how the columns in the wide format are differentiated in the long format.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the roundup of common approaches, you can look at "dplyr" + "tidyr", which can be used together like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf %>% gather(Time, Score, starts_with("Test"))
#          Date Student   Time Score
# 1  2007/02/01       A Test.1    80
# 2  2007/02/01       B Test.1    90
# 3  2007/02/01       C Test.1    75
# 4  2007/02/01       D Test.1    50
# 5  2007/02/01       A Test.2    90
# 6  2007/02/01       B Test.2    60
# 7  2007/02/01       C Test.2    70
# 8  2007/02/01       D Test.2    80
# 9  2007/02/01       A Test.3    70
# 10 2007/02/01       B Test.3    90
# 11 2007/02/01       C Test.3    80
# 12 2007/02/01       D Test.3    70
```

To get the specific form you're looking for, you can go a couple of steps further with `separate` and `select`:

```
mydf %>% 
  gather(Time, Score, starts_with("Test")) %>% 
  separate(Time, c("Stub", "Test")) %>% 
  select(-Stub)
#          Date Student Test Score
# 1  2007/02/01       A    1    80
# 2  2007/02/01       B    1    90
# 3  2007/02/01       C    1    75
# 4  2007/02/01       D    1    50
# 5  2007/02/01       A    2    90
# 6  2007/02/01       B    2    60
# 7  2007/02/01       C    2    70
# 8  2007/02/01       D    2    80
# 9  2007/02/01       A    3    70
# 10 2007/02/01       B    3    90
# 11 2007/02/01       C    3    80
# 12 2007/02/01       D    3    70
```